# What Pokemon can only be obtained after defeating the Elite Four?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have been trying to mop up the Pokedex as much as possible.  Thus far, I've been working through the regional Pokedexes.  However, are there any more Pokemon that can be obtained in Kalos that are not included in the Regional Pokedexes?  I'm trying to do as much as possible on my own - I don't have dozens of Friend Safaris knocking around or anything like that.

For example, a number of fossils will not spawn in the Glittering Cave until after the Elite Four - so until then, you cannot obtain, say, a Skull Fossil to restore into Crandios.

Are there any other cases like this?

Comment: No, the only other Pokemon exclusive to post game are found in Friend Safari, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the regional Pokédex in X and Y are already big in comparison to older generations and the amount of post-game content is limited.

Pokémon unlocked after beating the Elite Four are:

- An additional starter Pokémon (the one Shauna uses)
- Legendaries (all 3 of them)
- Friend Safari
- Fossils in Glittering Cave
- Ralts in Café Soleil

The rest of the Pokémon are available in Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many Pokémon that can only be obtained after defeating the elite four as well as the champion but the ones I know for sure are Deoxys, Zygaurd, Rayquaza, and Mewtwo and there is more it's just that I cannot list them all...